# Pick the right HDD for an unknown connector on HP 17-cn0021nr laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hard-disk, ssd

I'm looking for a recommendation on adding storage to the laptop if I don't want to swap the current m2 drive on my laptop.

I have a brand new [HP 17-cn0021nr laptop](https://support.hp.com/ee-en/document/c07117943), and I want to upgrade the storage capacity.  It has an installed m2 SSD, and I could either replace that or add another.  When looking over the motherboard(image 1), I noticed there is a connector labeled "HDD", near a spot that looks like its intended for a 2.5" drive.  I don't recognize this connector.

The motherboard has a label of "17N-8L-TGL," but I can't find specifications online for the unused port.

[image: Motherboard]  [image: Close-Up of connector][image: Alternate angle of Port]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a standard hard drive - what you're missing is a cable that breaks out the ZIF socket to a regular HDD. The [Service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06723426.pdf) is a great starting point.

You're looking for a `Hard drive cable L22526-001` - and you should be able to find it easily by searching for the part number `L22526-001`